# How do you sort or compare Strings in JavaScript based on a certain locale?

Tags: javascript, locale, string-comparison

I know there is a function called [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which you can use, and you can send in as the second argument a list of locales.

> string.localeCompare(compareString [, locales [, options]])

But if you look at the browser compatibility table, only Chrome supports it.

[image]

How do you sort or compare Strings in JavaScript based on a certain locale?

How does all the big websites do this, like ebay or amazon? They must have some kind of String sorting in the front-end.. right?

Comment: Why do they need to have String sorting in the front-end?

Comment: To avoid sending a back-end request, if we want to change the order of items in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need sorting, not compare?

Javascript array `sort` method sort strings on its **Unicode**(not ASCII) codes. You can sort array of strings to get it in alphabetical order.

`['Собака', 'Кошка'].sort()` will sort array to `["Кошка", "Собака"]` which is right in Ru_ru locale.

You can add compare function like this:

```
['Собака', 'Кошка', 'Свекла'].sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a[1] > b[1]?1:-1;
})
```

Javascript will compare strings by Unicode character by character. In my example compare is inside `a[1] > b[1]` on native low-level code. Return -1 or 1 needs for sort function to replace array elements.

Comment: If you know your native language it doesn't mean you can write anything you want just because other people don't understand you. I've corrected your answer, because SO isn't the place for filthy language.

Comment: Is this really ASCII? I thought it was only English-latin characters and symbols defined in ASCII. Regardless, lets say I want to sort "Кошка", "Собака" now based on en-US with array.sort?

Comment: Lets check first letter `('Кошка').charAt(0).charCodeAt(0)` is 1050? And you?